# Issue in creating Vectors from text in Mahout

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using Mahout 0.9 (installed on HDP 2.2) for topic discovery (Latent Drichlet Allocation algorithm). I have my text file stored in directory 
`inputraw` and executed the following commands in order

command #1:

```
mahout seqdirectory -i inputraw -o output-directory -c UTF-8
```

command #2:

```
mahout seq2sparse -i output-directory -o output-vector-str -wt tf -ng 3 --maxDFPercent 40 -ow -nv
```

command #3:

```
mahout rowid -i output-vector-str/tf-vectors/ -o output-vector-int
```

command #4:

```
mahout cvb -i output-vector-int/matrix -o output-topics -k 1 -mt output-tmp -x 10 -dict output-vector-str/dictionary.file-0
```

After executing the second command and as expected it creates a bunch of subfolders and files under the 
`output-vector-str` (named `df-count`, `dictionary.file-0`, `frequency.file-0`, `tf-vectors`,`tokenized-documents` and `wordcount`). The size of these files all looks ok considering the size of my input file however the file under ``tf-vectors` has a very small size, in fact it's only 118 bytes).

Apparently as the

```
`tf-vectors` is the input to the 3rd command, the third command also generates a file of small size. Does anyone know:
```

1. what is the reason of the file under

   ```
   `tf-vectors` folder to be that small? There must be something wrong.
   ```
2. Starting from the first command, all the generated files have a strange coding and are nor human readable. Is this something expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are as follows:

1. what is the reason of the file under tf-vectors folder to be that small?

The vectors are small considering you have given maxdf percentage to be only 40%, implying that only terms which have a doc freq(percentage freq of terms occurring throughout the docs) of less than 40% would be taken in consideration. In other words, only terms which occur in 40% of the documents or less would be taken in consideration while generating vectors.

2. what is the reason of the file under tf-vectors folder to be that small?

There is a command in mahout called the `mahout seqdumper` which would come to your rescue for dumping the files in "sequential" format to "human" readable format.
Good Luck!!